# R GUI Histogram menu. Error when clicking in variable list box

Tags: r, user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

As you know, I'm new in R and I'm trying to build a GUI. I've included a menu button to create a histogram. So the variables will be in a list box and when I chose the variable, the histogram should be made. The problem is that I'm getting the following error: ***"Error in hist.default: 'x' must be numeric"***. What's wrong with my code????
Could someone help me with that, please??? The code is below(updated).

Thank you in advance!

Now with updated code:

```
require(tcltk)
tt <- tktoplevel()
tkwm.title(tt, "Window")
tkgrid(tklabel(tt,text="Variables"))
tl <- tklistbox(tt,height=5,selectmode="single", background="white")
scr <- tkscrollbar(tt, repeatinterval=3, command=function(...) tkyview(tl,...))
tkgrid(tklabel(tt,text="Choose one:"), tl, scr)

dataframe <- tclVar("myData")
df <- get(tclvalue(dataframe))
vars <- c(names(df))
len <- length(df)

for (i in 1:len) tkinsert(tl,"end",vars [i])

tkselection.set(tl,len)
tkgrid(tklabel(tt, text = " "))

tkgrid.configure(scr,rowspan=4,sticky="nsw")
dfname = tclVar('myData')
varname = tclVar()

OnOK <- function(...)
{
  varchoice = vars[as.numeric(tkcurselection(tl))+1]
  hist(varchoice, col='blue')
}

OK.but <-tkbutton(tt,text="   OK   ",command=OnOK)
tkgrid(OK.but)
tkfocus(tt)
```

Comment: It looks like there is no data to plot. Compare with: `hist(numeric(0))`

Comment: Thank you James for your help. I modified my code a little bit. Now I'm getting the error from the example you showed me. "Error in hist.default: 'x' must be numeric".

Comment: I would suggest that you inspect what `var` actually is. I suspect it is not what you think it is. If you set `options(error=recover)` you will be able to browse the environment where the error occurs to check.

Comment: Sorry James, I've changed the code a little bit. But to make things clear, I have a dataset in RStudio called "myData" which contains 4 variables (2 of them numeric). When I click in the variable, to do the Histogram is when I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in tcl is a string, so perhaps when you get the value back from the widget you need to explicitly convert it to an int or float before using it in R.

Comment: Thank you Bryan! I thought I was doing that on the OnOK function: varchoice = vars[as.numeric(tkcurselection(tl))+1]. 
Not sure how to handle this.

Comment: @user2993749: unfortunately, the code you posted shows no occurrence of "hist.default", so I have no idea what it is or why it's not numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You need to plot the data, not the name of the data. Try something like `x <- get(varchoice, myData)` then `hist(x, col="blue")`.

Just for fun, I rewrote your example using gWidgets:

```
library(gWidgets2)
options(guiToolkit="tcltk")

myData <- mtcars
w <- gwindow("Make a histogram", visible=FALSE)
lyt <- glayout(cont=w)
lyt[1,1] <- "Variables"
lyt[2,1] <- "Choose one"
lyt[2,2:4] <- (tbl <- gtable(names(myData), cont=lyt))
size(tbl) <- c(200, 100)
lyt[3,1] <- (btn <- gbutton("ok", cont=lyt))

addHandlerClicked(btn, handler=function(h,...) {
  x <- get(svalue(tbl), myData)
  hist(x, col="blue")
})
visible(w) <- TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, jverzani! But I have to use Tcl/tk package. I changed my code a little bit and instead of listbox, I'm using radio buttons and it seems to work!